# Zend Controller not receiving data from Jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am trying to send one of my element's id, to my indexController, when clicked on it. Tried different ways taking help online but no luck. My controller is not receiving data from jQuery/Ajax. Can someone please help?

**My View: index.phtml**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row header-white">
            <div>
                <h1><span id="homepage">Shuffle Buddy</span></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="nav">  
            <ul>
                <li><div class="libox" id="a">A</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="b">B</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="c">C</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="d">D</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="e">E</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="f">F</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="g">G</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="h">H</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="i">I</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="j">J</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="k">K</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="l">L</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="m">M</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="n">N</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="o">O</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="p">P</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="q">Q</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="r">R</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="s">S</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="t">T</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="u">U</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="v">V</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="w">W</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="x">X</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="y">Y</div></li>
                <li><div class="libox" id="z">Z</div></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="wrapper">
            <div id="jsCarousel">
                <div class="subitems">
                    <?php
                       $_items = $this->items;
//                       $this->text = "hello";
//                       $this->controller->text = "Hello";
                    ?>
                    <p class="innersub"><?php echo $_items ['item'] . "<br>"; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>
                <div class="subitems"></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="bxdetails">
                <div class="subdetails">
                    <h4 style="text-align: center;"><b>Attributes</b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="subdetails">
                    <h4 style="text-align: center;"><b>Behavior</b></h4>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>    
    </div>  
</body>
```

**My Controller:  indexController.php**

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {


        $param = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
        if ($param != NULL) {
            $_custObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Shuffle();
            $this->view->items = $_custObj->getData($param);
        }
    }

}
```

**My jQuery/Ajax:   shuffle.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.libox').click(function () {
        var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(contentPanelId);
        ajaxFunction(contentPanelId);
              function ajaxFunction(contentPanelId) {
            var ajaxRequest;
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("upgrade your browser");
                return false;
            }

            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
                }
            };

            ajaxRequest.open("/default/index", true);
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajaxRequest.send("id=" + contentPanelId);
        }
        location.href = "/";
    });
});
```

Comment: did my answer helped you?please give me feedback

Comment: it is working Thanks. I just forgot to reply here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just edited your script and used jquery ajax function instead of javascript ajax .here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('.libox').click(function () {
    var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(contentPanelId);
    ajaxFunction(contentPanelId);

    location.href = "/";
});
 function ajaxFunction(contentPanelId) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'/index/test',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: contentPanelId},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })

    }
```

});